# Remove Registry Key From Apps And Programs

Tags: c#, windows, registry, uninstallation, registrykey

I have been searching on this topic for about 2 hours now, and all of the resources I find tell me the same thing. To delete a registry from the Windows 10 Apps and Programs list, use the following code:

```
string InstallerRegLoc = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
RegistryKey homeKey = (Registry.LocalMachine).OpenSubKey(InstallerRegLoc, true);
RegistryKey appSubKey = homeKey.OpenSubKey("App name");
if (null != appSubKey) {
    homeKey.DeleteSubKey("App name");
}
```

I have tried this, and it just isn't working for me. As we can see here, I have the program "Key Stats" in the registry:

[Registry app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTt0y.png)

Everything about this works great, but I can't remove this item from the registry. Here's the code I used to create the registry:

```
try {
    string guidText = "50038998-0755-41a2-8ae9-f9719f04c703";
    key = parent.OpenSubKey(guidText, true) ?? parent.CreateSubKey(guidText);

    if (key == null) {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Unable to create uninstaller '{0}\\{1}'", @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall", guidText));
    }

    Assembly asm = GetType().Assembly;
    Version v = asm.GetName().Version;
    string exe = "\"" + asm.CodeBase.Substring(8).Replace("/", "\\\\") + "\"";

    key.SetValue("DisplayName", "Key Stats");
    key.SetValue("ApplicationVersion", v.ToString());
    key.SetValue("Publisher", "My Company");
    key.SetValue("DisplayIcon", exe);
    key.SetValue("DisplayVersion", v.ToString(2));
    key.SetValue("URLInfoAbout", "");
    key.SetValue("Contact", "");
    key.SetValue("InstallDate", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
    key.SetValue("UninstallString", exe + " /uninstallprompt");
}
finally {
    if (key != null) {
        key.Close();
    }
}
```

I cannot remove the item from the registry though. Can someone please help me figure out why this isn't working?

Comment: `Everything about this works great...` Well, obviously not. What is the specific issue you are facing? Are there any errors? Or is the key simply not being removed? Are you sure the process has permission to remove keys?

Comment: @DanWilson The program cannot find the registry key "Key Stats". Also, yes, this is running with elevated permissions.

Comment: It looks like you used a guid for the key name ("Key Stats" is just the display name). have you tried replacing `"App name"` with `"50038998-0755-41a2-8ae9-f9719f04c703"`?